# CoreImage: Writing a reducer filter

Tags: metal, core-image

I'm trying to write a CIKernel that sums the values of all pixels in an image -- actually summing the absolute difference between two `CIImage`s as in a sum-of-absolute differences.

The documentation informs me that for loops are illegal unless the predicate can be tested at compile-time. The extent of an image can't, so I'm not sure how a kernel can iterate over samples and accumulate a value. Or is this even possible? Do I need to do the final summation outside of the kernel?

```
kernel vec4 coreImageKernel(sampler minuend, sampler subtrahend) {
vec4 retval = {0,0,0,0};
if destCoord().x == 0 && destCoord().y == 0 {

 int i,j;
 for(i = 0; i < samplerExtent(minuend).w ; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < samplerExtent(minuend).h ; j++) {
      vec2  dest =  {i,j};

      vec4 minSample = sample(minuend   , samplerTransform(minuend,dest));
      vec4 subSample = sample(subtrahend, samplerTransform(subtrahend,dest));

      vec4 sampleDiff = abs(minSample - subSample);
      retval += sampleDiff;
    }
  } 
}
return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is that you take a look at the recently introduced ability for Metal to render directly into a CoreImage pipeline. This example code shows a Metal compute kernel named grayscaleKernel, it is used to convert a RGBA input image to grayscale pixels as a step in a CoreImage pipeline. This is directly rendering, it does not go through an abstraction layer. The github project is [CoreImageMetalFilter](https://github.com/mdejong/CoreImageMetalFilter).

Comment: Hey MoDJ! Is it faster than using the standard `CIImage` with `CIKernel` subclass implementation?  (https://medium.com/@shu223/core-image-filters-with-metal-71afd6377f4) Or it's the same under the hood?

Comment: You are going to have to try it out yourself to see. The Apple implementation is constantly in flux, so your results will likely depend on iOS release. Thing is, conceptually at least, my implementation is the most straightforward way to invoke a Metal render from the CoreImage API. When it comes to actual performance, most of the time in any logic is spent simply reading and writing data inside the shaders, so actual performance may not be wildly different for different approaches.